# Why is there a error in the assembly language for loop on the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: assembly, raspberry-pi, arm

```
@ for.s
.section .data
msg1:
    .ascii "Hello1: %d\r\n"

msg2:
    .ascii "Hello2: %d\r\n"

.section .text
.global main

main:
    mov r2, #0          @ Initialize loop counter i to 0
loop:
    cmp r2, #5          @ Compare i with 5
    bge endloop         @ Branch to endloop if i >= 5
    ldr r0, =msg1       @ Load the address of the message string into r1
    mov r1, r2
    bl printf           @ Call printf
    add r2, r2, #1      @ Increment i
    b loop              @ Branch back to loop
endloop:
    mov r7, #1          @ Set up syscall number for exit
    mov r0, #0          @ Set exit status
    swi 0               @ Call syscall
```

```
$ gcc for.s
$ ./a.out
Hello1: 1
Hello2: 1
Hello1: 1
Hello2: 1
Hello1: 1
Hello2: 1
Hello1: 1
Hello2: 1
Hello1: 1
...
```

I want to implement logic similar to the following C code using assembly language to run on a Raspberry Pi 4, but I'm encountering errors. I have two questions:

1. Why is r2 always 1, causing it to never leave the loop?
2. I didn't call msg2 inside main, but it still prints the message. Why is this happening?

```
int main(){
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        printf("hello: %d\r\n", i);
    }
}
```

Comment: r0 to r3 are call-clobbered; use different regs for your loop vars.  And `.ascii` doesn't append a zero terminator, use `.asciz` for that, so when printf looks at the pointed-to string, it doesn't find the end until after the end of the second `.ascii`.